# Extract text using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to extract portion of a text using a regular expression. I need to get reference number from the text below. RegEx should return **89287661**

Any suggestion or a point in another direction is greatly appreciated.

```
The Data

    Reference Number        :89287661
    Order Date              :09/18/2015 03:51
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not your takeaway for regular expression, however some users would like you to believe otherwise. Show what you have tried.

Comment: I have spend 1h trying to create RegEx using https://regex101.com/, but it is insane hard to understand RegEx for me. That's why I have posted question without my RegEx code. And some people ready to help me instead of posting useless comments. I am not new to SO and know all rules.

Comment: Then apply them too. Read [ask]. You _should_ show what you have tried, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Then why use regex at all? `text.Split('\n').Where(p => p.Trim().StartsWith("Reference Number")).FirstOrDefault().Split(':')[1].Trim();`. You may add error checking, and here you are.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285733/327083  That said, when you typyed your question title into the "new question" box you saw a great big popup with a bunch of guidance specific to asking regex questions.  Did you read it?  I don't think so...

Comment: @Tomas: It's clear you are not a novice here. I suggest you add at least one of your tries to the question with 1 short sentence what problem with that you had, and your question will look much nicer for everyone. If you want to be upvoted, you should show understanding of the subject, IMHO. See vks's answer: it is the kind of answers you will get for "can-i-has-regex" questions. And as I said before, try to get the result without a regex - especially here, when you know the exact context - and only when the pattern is unknown, use regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\bReference Number\s*:)\d+\b
```

You can simply use `lookbehind` to grab the text.